# Angularjs load json into a specific div

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS but I love the framework.

What I have right now, is a (stub) single page that loads json data.

**JS**

```
var merlinoApp = angular.module('merlino', []);
merlinoApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
   ...
   $http.get('@Url.Action( "consoledatapull", "ConsoleElaborazioni")')
      .then(function (res) {
          $scope.jobs = res.data.jsonjobs;
          $scope.clienti = res.data.jsonclienti;
          $scope.console = res.data.jsonconsole;
      });
   ...
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="roll in jobs | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchJob | filter:searchCliente | filter:searchStato" class="console-row my-row">
    ...
    <div class="console-cell-id console-cell console-cell-padding console-cell-no-border-sx">{{ roll.id }}</div>
    ...
    <div ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" ng-class="{'console-cell-esito-selected' : collapsed}" class="console-cell-esito console-cell console-cell-no-border-sx">SHORT DESC</div>
    <div ng-show="collapsed" class="console-cell-esito-long console-cell console-cell-no-border-sx">{{ roll.esito }}</divng-show></div>
</div>
```

This populates `ng-repeat`, and the `ng-click` shows/hides the `ng-show div.
So far so good(?).

What Ì'm trying to achieve, is to load json data into

```
<div ng-show="collapsed" class="console-cell-esito-long...
```

if

```
<div ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" ng-class="{'console-cell...
```

is clicked.
That is each div of `ng-repeat`, can be loaded with specific data:

```
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="logelem in jsonlog">
                {{ logelem.log }}
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I thought about using a function:

```
<div ng-click="function(id)...
```

and then load json into a div identified by an id, so i used $index...
The result was, being able to load same data into all divs at once :/

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion woudl be to add the information to the jobs elements itself.

So for example, the `ng-click` would become:

```
<div ng-click="loadData(id, roll)">CLICK ME</div>
```

and then the loadData would be something like:

```
$scope.loadData = function(id, roll){
    // Do something
    roll.result = result;
}
```

and then you can use the `result` from that object in the view like you would do in other places. You can then for example hide the object where you want the final result until the variable `result` is defined.

I think this will be the easiest solution.

**Update from comments**

Why not change the collapsed value in the method? Or you could use a [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to listen to changes on the collapsed variable.

Comment: K, will try that.
One thing: i use <div ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed" collapsed to show/hide the underlying div, and to apply a class to the clicked one. Any ideas on how to do that with one fuction?

Comment: Why not change the `collapsed` value in the method? Or you could use a `$watch` to listen to changes on the `collapsed` variable. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: Kudos, both work. But i used <div ng-show="roll.id==jid" where jid is $scope.jid = 0; at first, and then changed to clicked id.

Comment: I would appreciate an upvote if the answer helped. If it was the best possible answer, you can also "Accept answer". This will help other users with the same problem to find the best solution.

Comment: Yes the answer helped a lot, and i'm sorry for my late response but i had a lot of work to finish.
P.S. I don't have enough rep. to upvote :/